# running async function once every minute

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

I was planning to get a data from the server every minute. However, if I run this code, this function is being called repeatedly. On the other hand, if I added `date.getMilliseconds == 0` in the condition, it won't process any results. 
Do you have any suggestions on how to run the function once every 1 minute?

```
async update() {
 var date = new Date();
 if (date.getSeconds() == 0) {
   var newdata = await getData(1);
   array.shift();
   array.push(newdata); 
  }
}
```

Comment: How often is `update` being called currently? (Can you just do `setInterval(update, 60000)`?)

Comment: look up `setInterval` and let us know if that solves your problem.

Comment: @CertainPerformance `update` function is a lifecycle callback provided by cocos. it runs every frame (in milliseconds).

Comment: Lodash has some great methods for stuff like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it looks like you don't have fine control over when `update` is called, one option would be to set a boolean to `true` every time `getSeconds() === 0` (set it to `false` otherwise), and then only run the real code when the flag is `false` *and* `getSeconds() === 0`:

```
let hasRun = false;
// ...
async update() {
 var date = new Date();
 const secs = date.getSeconds();
 if (secs !== 0) {
   hasRun = false;
 } else if (secs === 0 && hasRun === false) {
   hasRun = true;
   // your code
   var newdata = await getData(1);
   array.shift();
   array.push(newdata); 
  }
}
```

An alternative that might require less resources due to not creating `Date`s every frame would be to have a *separate* function that toggles the boolean, set with a `setInterval` that runs every 60 seconds, no `Date`s involved:

```
let hasRun = false;
setInterval(() => hasRun = false, 60000);
async update() {
  if (hasRun) return;
  hasRun = true;
  // your code
}
```

(of course, you could also try `setInterval(update, 60000)` if the framework allows it)

Comment: I imagine `update` gets called via [`requestAnimationFrame()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Comment: Why not just a setInterval?